# Laravel 5.2 - php artisan fails with - The process has been signaled with signal "5"

Tags: php, macos, laravel

So I am trying to install a laravel app on my Mac OSX 10.10 and when running composer install it gets to the post scripts "clear-compiled / optimize" and fails with the following error:

```
> post-install-cmd: php artisan clear-compiled


  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The process has been signaled with signal "5".


Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:375
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->wait() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:203
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:62
 Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:204
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:94
 Composer\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatchScript() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:337
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InstallCommand.php:134
 Composer\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:259
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:844
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:192
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:189
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:123
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:99
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:43
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24

install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I have been able to find very little in the way of explanation on this error and the few places I have found have offered up things like updating SVN or git and some other off the wall, seemingly unrelated solutions. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
composer install --no-scripts
```

Comment: well of course that works because it skips the post scripts that are causing the problem.....but that doesn't tell me why this is happening or how to run those commands without it failing.

Comment: You set up composer globally right ? Try "composer self-update" then "composer install --prefer-dist"

Comment: Avoiding the scripts is not an option @Piya. I did run those two commands and it still hasn't helped

Comment: Do you have a debugger ?

Comment: Then I am a little confused. Because this problem is quite rare.

Comment: you and me both :)

Comment: I would like to know the solution, if u find any :)

Comment: we actually gave up and made me a vm to use.

Comment: Thats sad to hear !